# In Android Studio, the button does not operate when it is clicked. It doesn't crash, but does nothing

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am implementing an application that does simply maneuvers when the button is clicked with Android Studio(Java). For example, when Button 1 is clicked, The app shall move the screen to another screen. But it does... nothing. No error code while decoding, no error message floated, just, nothing happens. And of course, I didn't set the Button as invisible, I did set the basic setting in AndroidManifest.xml.

Here is a piece of code I made:
In MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidbluecon1;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button sub_button = findViewById(R.id.button_sub_activity);
        sub_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent_introduction = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SubActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_introduction);
        });
    }
    //This one is for secondary uses, 
    public void openSecondActivity() {
        Intent sub_intent = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
        startActivity(sub_intent);
    }
}
```

In activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_sub_activity"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next Page"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In SubActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidbluecon1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);

        ImageButton back_to_main = findViewById(R.id.imageBluetooth);
        back_to_main.setOnClickListener(view -> backtomainActivity());

        ImageButton go_to_alarm = findViewById(R.id.imageAlarm);
        go_to_alarm.setOnClickListener(view -> gotoalarmActivity());

        ImageButton go_to_list = findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
        go_to_list.setOnClickListener(View -> gotolistActivity());

        ImageButton btnInstructions = findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
        btnInstructions.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent_instructions = new Intent(getBaseContext(), instructions.class);
            startActivity(intent_instructions);
        });
    }
    public void backtomainActivity() {
        Intent backintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(backintent);
    }
    public void gotoalarmActivity(){
        Intent alarmintent = new Intent(this, Alarmintent.class);
        startActivity(alarmintent);
    }
    public void gotolistActivity() {
        Intent listintent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
        startActivity(listintent);
    }
    public void gotoinstructions() {
        Intent gotoinstructions = new Intent(this, instructions.class);
        startActivity(gotoinstructions);
    }
}
```

In activity_sub.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SubActivity"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="399dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="231dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:contentDescription="Introduction Page"
        android:src="@drawable/main_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/instructions"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintBounds" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="216dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="183dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagelist"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/instructions"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageAlarm"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="173dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="281dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageBluetooth"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/alarm_page"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageBluetooth"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="173dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="279dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageAlarm"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bluetooth_page"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagelist"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="183dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="77dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/instructions"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/list_page"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Androidbluecon1"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".SubActivity"
            android:label="Main Activity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="List Screen"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Alarmintent"
            android:label="Alarm Screen"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".instructions"
            android:label="Instructions" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Is there anything wrong, feel free to comment below. Thanks.